# Passing Data from PostgreSQL Database into an HTML with Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm currently trying to pass in data from a database (PostgreSQL) into an HTML file with Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_sql('select * from "DATABASE".table_name Limit 100', con = engine )
```

A snippet of the HTML file:

```
people = """

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <h1>PERSON</h1>
</div>
</div>

...


</html>

"""
```

Now, I want to replace the variable **PERSON** with a variable from the PostgreSQL database. e.g. Joe.

On the Python side, my attempt so far:

```
#we want HTML files that have the name of people from the DB attached to the HTML file
for i,rows in df.iterrows():
    var1 = df.loc[i]['col1']
fileName = (f"people{name}.html")
people = open(fileName,"w")

#now place name of person inside HTML file, at PERSON with a name from the DB
for line in logData:
    people.write(line.replace("PERSON", var1))
people.close()
```

This isn't obviously working and I've come against a wall of how best to proceed.

So basically need to generate a load of HTML files for a list of people from the DB and insert a name inside the PERSON place-holder in the HTML file. The name come from the DB.

Any advice/knowledge of you might make a start on this problem, please let me know.

Comment: It's a pretty broad question, so it doesn't surprise me that you didn't get the answers you were looking for. Have you looked at something like [Flask](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/)?

Comment: @NicoGriffioen. Yeah I know, never had to do anything like this before. Essentially just trying to place data into an html file using python